# Allow the option to stay anonymous when clicking on chat links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, privacy, automatic-comments

When reading comments or posts, there are often links to chat, usually with this message:

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.

But sometimes the text is different, and it is not obvious from the link text that it is a chat link.

The problem is that if someone clicks on the link, his presence is immediately revealed, by an animation on the right of the screen.

[image: presence revealed]

The solution to this is to open the link in a private window, and then the animation doesn't show. But this is easy to forget.

Would it be possible to have this behaviour as default? Personally I don't like my presence revealed, unless I decide to comment or answer.

Comment: Why don't you just browse everything in an incognito window?

Comment: @user202729 for example, you can't vote unless logged in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can understand why you wouldn't want to join a room sometimes. Rewriting the room link to the chat transcript would easily solve this.

Here's a userscript for that [ChatTranscriptsByDefault](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatTranscriptsByDefault.user.js) ([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ChatTranscriptsByDefault.user.js))

Once you've caught up with the conversation, at the bottom of the chat transcript there's a link to join the room if you wish to contribute to the discussion.

If the timestamps in chat transcripts throw you off (it's in UTC), use [ChatTranscriptHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatTranscriptHelper.user.js) ([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ChatTranscriptHelper.user.js)) to convert them into local time.

---

Userscripts require [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) to be installed on your browser.

If you are on Android, your browser options are [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) *(recommended)* or [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it's **not possible** to tell a browser to open a link in a incognito session.

That aside, if this were possible, it'd be rather inconvenient for those that *do* wish to participate.

They would have to log in every time they open a chat link like that, or they'd have to manually switch to a normal session.

Comment: Switching to a normal window isn't that hard... Just copy paste the url form the incognito window to the normal one. But if you say that it is technically impossible, then there is little point discussing it. Perhaps a setting somewhere to not log in to chat would be better.

Comment: @user000001: 1: Copy the url, 2: open a new window, 3: paste the new url, 4: close the incognito window, 5: hit return on the new window. Those are way too many steps for the primary use-case.

Comment: I generalized the title to focus on the problem, and not on the proposed solution, there must be some method to accommodate both use-cases

Comment: Not really. You'll just need to remember to open the link in a incognito window.

Comment: What if there was a "reveal presence/identity" button in the chat window? It you are worried about the extra click, it could be clicked automatically when posting a chat message.

Comment: That would mean users that have (several) chat tabs open by default would have to check-in on every tab, when they restart their browser / PC.

Comment: @user000001 apart from the general advice "hover and check before you click" you could always do a simple userscript that adds an onclick handler to links that'd directly take you to a chatroom and join it that prompts you with a "This will make you join a chat room - are you sure?" (or even a more complicated one which also offers to take you to the transcript so you can have a read first and where the normal ui then offers a "join this room" option - which seems to be what you might be after/find useful).

Comment: @JonClements: That seems like a good idea actually, I'll look into implementing it.